# How to do proper Reflection of base Interface methods

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, interface

I have 2 interfaces and 2 classes that I investigate via Reflection:

- IParent
- IChild - derives from IParent
- Parent
- Child - derives from Parent

Strange thing for me is the fact that when I look through reflection on IChild type I don't find IParent method.

Same code applied to Child type works as expected - reflection shows Parent method.

```
interface IParent
{
     void ParentMethod();
}

interface IChild : IParent
{
     void ChildMethod();
}

class Parent 
{
     public void ParentMethod(){}
}

class Child : Parent
{
     public void ChildMethod(){}
}

void Main()
{
    //investigate derived interface
     Type t = typeof(IChild);
     var info = t.GetMethod("ChildMethod");//ok
     Console.WriteLine(info); 
     info = t.GetMethod("ParentMethod");//returns null!
     Console.WriteLine(info); 
     //investigate derived class
     t = typeof(Child);
     info = t.GetMethod("ChildMethod");//ok
     Console.WriteLine(info);
     info = t.GetMethod("ParentMethod");//ok
     Console.WriteLine(info);
}
```

Please explain such behaviour?

Is there any workaround to reflect base interface's methods from the derived interface's type?

Comment: `Parent` does not implement `IParent`...typo?

Comment: Good question. I learnt something reading the answers. Hadn't needed to know it yet, but knowledge is power...

Comment: @Jamiec No, it's not a typo. Just showing the differences in reflecting inherited classes vs interfaces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although, we use the interfaces as the same way we use inheritance (":"); interfaces are not inherited; they are to be implemented. In such a case; inheritance is confused with implementation since they are defined using the same operator (":").

As a summary;
`IA : IB` and `A:IA` means; any class implementing IA, shall implement IB. In this case; A shall implement IA and IB.

`A:B` means A class inherits B class; it does not implement.

The confusion here derives from using the same operator (":").

Check this page [interface inheritance](http://www.roxolan.com/2009/04/interface-inheritance-in-c.html)

Answer (score 11):

If you are dealing with an interface, use

```
t.GetInterfaces()
```

then you can check for methods on the types returned above.

Finding interface members by name is not relyable, be mindful that whilst in C# interface members cannot be renamed on implementation, in the CLR the names may be modified. (IDisposable.Dispose() is sometimes renamed to Close). In il there is an instruction called `.implements` that allows one to change names. I believe VB.Net also has this feature.

Answer (score 6):

The *base interfaces* of an interface (in this case `IParent` is the base interface of `IChild`) are *explicit base interfaces*. Inheritence is an unfortunate word for interfaces, because classes, structures, and other interfaces never *inherit* from interfaces, they simply implement the contract that the base interfaces define.

When you derive `IChild` from `IParent` (note I did not say inherit), it does not define the `ParentMethod` method, it simply says *anything that implements me, must also implement `IParent`*.

The reason it works when you reflect on an actual type, is because implementing an interface actually does define that method signatures in the type itself, and that's not the case with interfaces.

This is due to a process that occurs by the compiler called *interface mapping*, which is defined as the process of locating interface members in an implementing class or struct, but this does not occur for the interface itself.

When you reflect upon an interface, interface mapping does *not* occur, so only the interface itself is reflected.

```
Type t = typeof(IChild);
```

The type information will only contain type information explicitly about `IChild`.

```
Type t = typeof(Child);
```

Here the process of interface mapping *does* occur. When you reflect upon the type of `Child` for a method named `ParentMethod`, each base interface is examined until a match is found.

This part of the language design. You can read more about it in section 13.1.4 of the C# Programming Language (Fourth Edition) or section 20.1.2 of the ECMA spec.

You can work around it somewhat by doing *interface reimplementation*, but it requires some extra code.

```
interface IParent
{
    void ParentMethod();
}

interface IChild
{
    new void ParentMethod(); // Reimplement IParent.ParentMethod()
    void ChildMethod();
}
```

This would work.

```
Type t = typeof(IChild);
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("ParentMethod");
```

Because of interface reimplementation, `IChild` now contains a method signature of `ParentMethod`.