# Getting list of interface methods available in derived interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class A as:

```
public class A: ParentA, IA
{
    public void func()
    {
    }
    public void ConsumableMethod()
    {
    }
    public void MethodA()
    {
    }
    public void ConsumableMethodFromIB()
    {
    }
}

public interface IA : IB
{
    void ConsumableMethod();
}

public interface IB
{
    void ConsumableMethodFromIB();
}

public abstract class ParentA
{
    public abstract void MethodA();

    public void MethodB()
    {
    }
}
```

I want a list of methods which are available in interface IA. For which I'm doing something like this:

```
var methods = typeof(IA).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | 
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

By calling ***GetMethods*** on A, I'm getting a list of methods declared solely in A (i.e. func), method implemented in parent abstract class (i.e. MethodB) and implemented interface methods (i.e. ConsumableMethod & ConsumableMethodFromIB).

What I want is ***methods available in IA (including methods from IB)***. I'm currently getting 'ConsumableMethod' only, by calling GetMethods on IA. How can I get '**ConsumableMethodFromIB**' also ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you're getting/not getting here. Can you please update your question, say what `IA` is, what `methods` returns and what you'd expect it to return? Also, what *parent abstract class* are you talking about? There is none in your question. And, interface can't *implement* another interface. It can **extend** it, but never *implement*.

Comment: You can't get not implemented methods, as there is no meta information about them in that classes.

Comment: It's on the same line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550970/how-to-do-proper-reflection-of-base-interface-methods

Answer (score 4):

As you already noticed, `GetMethods` will not return you methods of "parent" interface. `GetMethods` might return inherited methods (unless you use `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` flag) - that is why you see all those methods when you call `GetMethods` on type `A`, they are all either belong to this class or inherited from parent class.

If you want to get methods of "parent" interface, you will have to explore them manually, like this:

```
static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetMethods(Type type) {
    foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static |
                                               BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)) {
        yield return method;
    }
    if (type.IsInterface) {
        foreach (var iface in type.GetInterfaces()) {
            foreach (var method in GetMethods(iface)) {
                yield return method;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find what you look for by using this set of methods/properties :

- `typeof(A).GetInterfaces()`
- `typeof(A).GetInterfaceMap(...)`
- `MethodInfo.DeclaringType`

and make the differential.